# How do I end a for-loop without printing numerous times in an if-else statement after parsing information from a JSON URL

Tags: python, json, database, for-loop, parsing

I have my code set up where the user can pull information from a JSON URL via user input. However, I want to add a condition that tells the user "No Records" when the information the user inputs cannot be found. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json")

json_test = response.json()

print("Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): ")
user_state = input()
print("Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): ")
user_date = input()


count = 0
for i in json_test:
    i = count
    count = count + 1
    state = (json_test[i]['state'])
    dates = (json_test[i]['date'])
    death = (json_test[i]['death'])
    positive = (json_test[i]['positive'])
    positiveIncrease = (json_test[i]['positiveIncrease'])
    deathIncrease = (json_test[i]['deathIncrease'])
    
    if state == user_state and str(dates) == user_date:
        cv_state = state
        cv_date = dates
        cv_death = death
        cv_positive = positive
        cv_positiveIncrease = positiveIncrease
        cv_deathIncrease = deathIncrease
        print("===============")
        print("State: " + str(cv_state))
        print("Date: " + str(cv_date))
        print("Positive Cases: " + str(cv_positive))
        print("Death(s): " + str(cv_death))
        print("===============")
    else:
        print("No Record")
```

The code works If I input the correct information, but it still outputs "No Records" numerous times even if the record was found. Here is the output:

```
===============
State: AK
Date: 20200315
Positive Cases: None
Death(s): 0
===============
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
No Record
```

It outputs "No Record" way more but how do I combat this to where it only shows No Record once and only if the records cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

This might work fine:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/states/daily.json")

json_test = response.json()

print("Enter the state for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. TX): ")
user_state = input()
print("Enter the date for which the COVID data should be retrieved (e.g. 20201219): ")
user_date = input()
status = False

count = 0
for i in json_test:
    i = count
    count = count + 1
    state = (json_test[i]['state'])
    dates = (json_test[i]['date'])
    death = (json_test[i]['death'])
    positive = (json_test[i]['positive'])
    positiveIncrease = (json_test[i]['positiveIncrease'])
    deathIncrease = (json_test[i]['deathIncrease'])

    if state == user_state and str(dates) == user_date:
        status = True
        cv_state = state
        cv_date = dates
        cv_death = death
        cv_positive = positive
        cv_positiveIncrease = positiveIncrease
        cv_deathIncrease = deathIncrease
        print("===============")
        print("State: " + str(cv_state))
        print("Date: " + str(cv_date))
        print("Positive Cases: " + str(cv_positive))
        print("Death(s): " + str(cv_death))
        print("===============")
if(status==False):
    print("No Records")
```

Comment: However, when I add a break statement, it stop the whole for-loop. When I input data that is valid, it would still print out "No Records" because the for-loop has been stopped before it could loop through the JSON file and pull the info from it.

Comment: Modified the code, added a variable status which is initially False, now if there is atleast one value which satisfies then status will become True. If after for loop completes status is still False, it will print "No Records"